# Team Foundation Server 2008 to 2015 Project Migration

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to move the whole team project data(source files and work items…) from TFS 2008 to TFS 2015. Can anybody tell me the detailed step by step process, as I have never done migration within TFS versions?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do a upgrade for your TFS. Direct upgrade to TFS 2015 is supported only from TFS 2010 and newer. If your TFS deployment is on an older version than that, you will need to upgrade to TFS 2015 in multiple hops. For your scenario, you are on TFS 2008 you could upgrade to TFS 2010 or TFS 2012 first and then to TFS 2015.

The general process for upgrading an existing deployment of Team Foundation Server is to:

1. Prepare your environment. New [system requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements) may require you to upgrade hardware or software.
2. Expect the best, prepare for the worst. The single most important step you can take here is to ensure you have a complete and consistent set of [database backups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan).
3. Do the upgrade!
4. Configure new features. Depending on what version you upgraded from, you may need to [configure each team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access to some of the new features made available.

[Walk through an upgrade from TFS 2005 to TFS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/tfs-2005-to-2015).

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. I want to move team project folders from TFS 2008 to TFS 2015. I have opened both the TFS(2008 and 2015) projects in Visual Studio 2012. Now how should I carry out the transition of project folders from 2008 to 2015 within Visual Studio?

Comment: Upgrade TFS is full data transfer, after upgrade, you'll see all data in new TFS.